# Does codimension-1 collapsing with bounded curvature have boundary?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Let $(M^n,g_i)$ be a sequence of smooth complete Riemannian manifold with $|sec_{g_i}| \le 1$. Suppose $(M_i^n,g_i)$ converges to a limit space $(X^{n-1},d)$ in the Gromov-Hausdorff sense, where the Hausdoff dimension of $X$ is $n-1$.

Can we show that $X$ contains no boundary point? Here, a point is a boundary point of $X$ if its tangent cone is isometric to $\mathbb R^{n-2} \times \mathbb R_+$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flat Klein bottles can collapse to a line segment.